# Trigger link click on Ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to trigger a link click on Ajax success. The code that I currently have is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
//Ajax Options
success: function(value) {
    jQuery('.parent_selector').html(jQuery(value).find('.child_selector'));
    jQuery('.test-link').trigger('click');
},
error: function() {
    //alert(error);
} });
```

The Ajax part works fine and I am able to load the `.parent_selector` div with Ajax response data. After this I need to trigger a link click for which I have `jQuery('.test-link').trigger('click');` in the above code. However, the link click is never triggered. To check, I moved `jQuery('.test-link').trigger('click');` within `jQuery(document).ready(function()` to see whether the link is triggered on page load. But it does not work there as well. The next thing I tried was to put `jQuery('.test-link').trigger('click');` within click event of another link, as below:

```
jQuery('section[role="main"]').on('click', '.another-link', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

jQuery('.test-link').trigger('click');
```

});

Voila!, it works within a click event of another link. So, I am really confused as to what am I doing wrong here. Why `jQuery('.test-link').trigger('click');` does not want to play nice with Ajax success call?

Comment: Instead of jQuery('.test-link').trigger('click');, you can just use jQuery('.test-link').click();

Comment: @SKS jQuery('.test-link').click(); is behaving the same way as jQuery('.test-link').trigger('click'); No luck.

Comment: Is .test-link coming back as part of your AJAX response (value)?

Comment: @John That was a comment, not an answer. What do you do when the link is clicked? just a GET request to another page or do you have click handler?

Comment: @SKS The .test-link is not part of the data returned via Ajax. The .test-link simply hides/unhides couple of divs for creating a tabbed effect on the page.

Comment: have you try to put setTimeout() on the trigger? sometimes it works...
setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('.test-link').trigger('click');
 },400)

Comment: Can you look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uaBuj/ , i reproduced the behavior you describes, and it seems to work. Would be interesting to know how different you are doing it in your code.

Answer (score 4):

When you use:

```
$(".test_link").trigger("click")
// or
$(".test_link").click()
```

You are executing only `onclick` events of the links it can be by jQuery bind or `onclick` attribute, but it doesn't open the page what you have in `href`.

So if you want to open the link which you have in `href` you need to so something like following:

```
window.location = $(".test_link").attr("href");
```

Other reason I can think of is you are getting the link dynamically and after getting it you are not adding any handler on the click event. jQuery "live" can solve the problem, but I would prefer to use `delegate` if you know what the parent container is.

Answer (score 0):

If your link is part of the value returned from your AJAX call the click function is not bound to that object.  Try using .live() to bind the function to the object instead of .click().

```
<script>
jQuery('.test-link').live('click', function(){
   //your function stuff
});
</script>
```

This will allow you to create dynamic content and not have to rebind that function everytime the link is created.

Comment: `on()` replaces `live()` in jQuery 1.7

Comment: @ManselUK I didn't realize that was depracted.  The use of .on() is different than .live().  Maybe the problem is that the event handler is not delegated properly. [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) about a quarter of the way down.

Comment: @Nick The .test-link isn't part of the Ajax data returned by the server. Hence, it is always present on the page and therefore would not require use of on() or live().

Comment: @John Does the AJAX happen before or after the click function is defined?  Also are the click function and AJAX call within the same scope?

Comment: @Nick The Ajax happens on user interaction. By then the page has already loaded completely and the click function defined. I am not sure what exactly do you mean by within same scope? Can you please clarify.

Comment: @John If you defined your click function within another function it only lives within that parent function.  Same thing with variables, unless defined in a global scope.  If both AJAX and click functions are defined within the same scope (function) than it should work.  Can you show more code?

Comment: @Nick I am unsure about the scope of the click function of the .test-link. The .test-link though defined by me in the code, it references a plugin. The code of which I am afraid cannot be shared due to licensing terms. I have tried to keep things simple here. Let's keep Ajax out of this and only concentrate on $(document).ready(function(). The click event for .test-link does not get triggered there as well. However, the interesting part is that when wrapped inside click event of .another-link and when I click .another-link the trigger to .test-link fires.

Comment: @John  Do you have a link to your example?

Comment: @Nick Well, It's a local install. Let me see if I can get back to you with some additional snippet from the plugin itself. I appreciate the help provided!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test').live('click', function() {
    window.alert("works");            
});

$('#test').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/CHUsU/1/embedded/result/

In some browsers you *might* get a security sandbox warning so if it doesn't work, throw the lot onto your hdd.

-Miles

Answer (score -1):

Just replace

```
 jQuery('.test-link').trigger('click');
```

with

```
 jQuery('.test-link').click();
```

or

```
$('.test-link').click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `$('.test-link').click()`